# How to avoid advertisement in YouTube

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, youtube

I would like to know if there is a way to avoid the advertisement in YouTube videos in YouTube application for Android  ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a rooted phone or tablet, you can install [YouTube AdAway](http://repo.xposed.info/module/ma.wanam.youtubeadaway). It is an xposed framework module that stops/blocks videos ads in the Youtube app.

You also need to install the xposed framework, and activate the module.

Disclaimer: I am still using version 11.45.59 of the Youtube app and the module works as stated above. I am not sure about more recent versions

Edit: Try [Youtube Vanced](https://vanced.app/), a modified version of the Youtube app that prevents ads and has other features.